# Devexpress: How to set EditValue of BarEditItem in code

Tags: devexpress

I have a variable AA, I want the text of BarEditItem update when AA updates.

It doesn't work when I set BarEditItem.editvalue=AA in code or set EditValue="{Binding AA, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" in XAML.

Would anyone suggest how to do?

Comment: hi, did you check -> EditValue="{Binding Path=AA}" ?

Answer (score 0):

1. To set EditValue of BarEditItem in Code as the question states simply name your BarEditItem for example in XAML like

   **BarEditItem x:Name="myBarEditItem"**

Then in your code behind you can simply do this

```
myBarEditItem.EditValue = "new value";
```

2. If you want to bind it to a variable you can do this in your xaml.

   EditValue = "Binding AA"

and in your code behind you have to extend your Window from INotifyPropertyChanged like

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged{
```

and then implement ProperyChanged like

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Now as last step you have to use

```
OnPropertyChanged("AA");
```

and implement it like

```
public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
```

For me it works and also updates the value during program is running. Thanks